# Contextual Action Bar menu forces items into overflow menu when there is room

Tags: android

I have a contextual action bar with three menu items, so only three icons. There is definitely room on the cab, but only one icon shows and the other two are forced into the oveflow menu. If I use android:showAsAction="always" in all three menu items then they all show and there is room. However, I would rather use android:showAsAction="ifRoom" with the result that all three icons show. Have tried deleting android:title on each item, but that still resulted in the oveflow menu, so I know it's not trying to put the title in.

```
<item android:id="@+id/delete_quiz"
    android:title="DeleteQuiz"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/load_quiz"
    android:title="LoadQuiz"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/start_quiz"
    android:title="StartQuiz"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

The icon I'm using is ic_menu_close_clear_cancel for each menu item.

Has anyone had a similar experience? What did you do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find solution to this? am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using the layoutWeight attribute. layoutWeight will NOT work with Relative Layout.

set the value of layoutWeight between 0 to 1

0 - Greedy (Will take the full space)

1 - Generous (Will take only as much as needed)

Try to fiddle between 0 to 1, and u will hit the spot, try 0.25, or 0.5 for all of them.

Comment: Tried one more thing. Changed my icons to ldpi (18 x 18 pixels) for a test on Platform 4.03 Level 15(WQVGA400). Still same problem. When all 4 icons are " android:showAsAction="ifRoom" " only one icon shows and the rest are put into the overflow menu. But changing to " android:showAsAction="always" " results in all 4 icons showing, proving there was room.